OpenPyXL Duplicate and populate row
I'm trying to copy a row, based upon cell value, and edit the 6th colmn value with the 'VAL' key values.
For example row 10 contains "A1"
The first column must get the first value of the VAL: A1 (AAA) and the second A1: (BBB).
Now it populates the first (and second) with the second BBB value.
I know it's because of the loop that overwrites the first value, but I can't seem to pinpoint the point where to make it skip after the first itteration.
Any help is appreciated!
Please see the sample code:
from openpyxl.utils import rows_from_range
from openpyxl import load_workbook


# key values:
VAL = {
    'A1': ['AAA', .5, 'BBB', .5],
    'B1': ['CCC', .333, 'DDD', .333, 'EEE', .333],
    'C1': ['CCC', .5, 'DDD', .5],
    'D1': ['FFF', .05, 'BBB', .4, 'AAA', .4, 'EEE', .05, 'GGG', .1],
    'E1': ['AAA', .5, 'GGG', .5]
}


def copy_range(range_str, ws, offset, insert_point):
    """ Copy cell values and style to the new row using offset"""

    # Insert empty Row
    ws.insert_rows(insert_point, offset)

    for row in rows_from_range(range_str):
        for cell in row:

            dst_cell = ws[cell].offset(row=offset, column=0)
            src_cell = ws[cell]

            flag = 0
            for key in VAL:
                if dst_cell.value == key:
                    for i in range(int(len(VAL[key]) / 2)):
                        flag += 2
                        dst_cell.value = list(VAL[key])[flag - 2]

            # Populate new Cell value
            src_cell.value = dst_cell.value


file = 'C:/TEMP/TEST/File.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(file)
ws = wb[f'Sheet1']

# start at row 4
for row in ws.iter_rows(4):
    for cell in row:

        # look at column 6 for key value
        if cell.column == 6 and 'A1' in cell.value:

            # Get Rownumber to insert
            insert_point = cell.row

            # Row range to be copied
            row_range = f'A{cell.row}:P{cell.row}'

            # Offset to the new row
            row_offset = 1

            # Copy cell values to new row
            copy_range(row_range, ws, row_offset, insert_point)

    # Save workbook
    wb.save(f"{file}--edit.xlsx")


if cell.column is 6 and 'A1' in cell.value is 6 do you mean == 6 ?

Are you attempting to achieve something like the resultant Sheet from the example I used.
If not you're going to have to provide what your existing and expected Sheets are.
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# key values:
VAL = {
    'A1': ['AAA', .5, 'BBB', .5],
    'B1': ['CCC', .333, 'DDD', .333, 'EEE', .333],
    'C1': ['CCC', .5, 'DDD', .5],
    'D1': ['FFF', .05, 'BBB', .4, 'AAA', .4, 'EEE', .05, 'GGG', .1],
    'E1': ['AAA', .5, 'GGG', .5]
}

def write_row(wks, r, k):
    offset = 1

    ws.insert_rows(r, offset)

    for c in range(1, len(VAL[k])+1):
        val_value = VAL[k][c-1]
        wks.cell(row=r, column=c).value = val_value
        wks.cell(row=r+offset, column=c).value = val_value


file = 'File.xlsx--edit.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(file)
ws = wb[f'Sheet1']

for key in VAL:
    for cell in ws['F']:
        if isinstance(cell.value, str):
            if key in cell.value:
                write_row(ws, cell.row, key)
                break

wb.save(f"edit--{file}")

And note that wb.save(f"{file}--edit.xlsx") will result in a file called 'File.xlsx--edit.xlsx' which is fine if that's what your after, but maybe as I have changed it is better; 'edit--File.xlsx'. 
Original Sheet

Resultant Sheet


Thank you for your help!!
It's really all about the "F" or "6th" column. The copy/duplicate function and the different values it must write to both cells/rows.
For what I can see is that the function you wrote, places the AAA and BBB values on the same row, different columns.
I need it to write AAA to for example row 10 and
BBB to row 11, in the same column.
The '--edit.xlsx' is, for now during the testing fase, fine, but will alter after.
You've already helped me a lot with your comment! Thank you!!
